# How to simplify chain of predicates in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, boolean, predicate, chain

I have a chain of predicate clauses, something like this

```
student?.firstName?.equals("John") ?: false &&
student?.lastName?.equals("Smith") ?: false &&
student?.age?.equals(20) ?: false &&
student?.homeAddress?.equals("45 Boot Terrace") ?: false &&
student?.cellPhone?.startsWith("123456") ?: false
```

I have found that instead of **&&** it's possible to switch to Boolean predicate **and()**, but overall it doesn't make code more concise.

Is there is a way in Kotlin to simplify such expression?

Comment: `student?.run { firstName("John") && lastName("Smith") .. }` https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#run

Comment: it will not compile because of nullable types. Expression **&&** only works with safe non nullable types

Comment: `student?.firstName?.equals("John") ?: false` could be simplified to `student?.firstName == "John"`, &c.  (Because `==` handles nulls.)

Comment: instead of writing `?: false` you can also just write `== true`...

Comment: is it a better practice to use comparison instead of elvis operator? I see the difference between those two operators `?:` _is same as if else_, wherease `==` _is only comparison_

Comment: IMO elvis is clearer than `== true` in this situation.

Comment: If it is a data class and if you're comparing all properties, I would suggest to create student object with expected values, then just compare two data class objects like (yourStudent == expectedStudent).

Comment: just because you can doesn't mean you have to ;-) hmmm... I just saw that Intellij has its own inspection telling you that you could replace that `?: false` to `== true`... I don't mind really... I find both variants not so nice... I don't even mind writing `if (student != null && student.run { lastName == ..... })` in this case... maybe would even prefer it in this case...

Comment: @Rolan, Intellij suggests both converting `?:` to `==` and vice versa if you navigate to tips :) Personally, I coded in Java a lot and found writing boilerplate code over and over again. So I would like to replace if null checks wherever it's possible with function calls and I think this is a good place to start from.

Comment: @kirillleonov interesting... but also strange... one is implemented as inspection (and is therefore marked accordingly in the editor) and the other is an intention, which one can use, but which can not be marked as error/warning/info or whatever...  doesn't seem congruent to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone who participated! Here is a final version of the code with notes:

```
student?.run {
  firstName == "John" &&
  lastName == "Smith" &&
  age == 20 &&
  homeAddress == "45 Boot Terrace" &&
  cellPhone.orEmpty().startsWith("123456")
} ?: false
```

1. Scope function `run {}` is called on an object `student`
2. `equals` is replaced by `==` to compare boolean as well as `null` values
3. return type of scope function is nullable, so elvis operator is used `?: false`. Another option is to use `== true`, but it's your personal preference

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
val result = listOf(
    student.firstName == "John",
    student.lastName == "Smith",
    student.age == 20,
    student.cellPhone.orEmpty().startsWith("123456")
).all { it }
```

or

```
fun isAllTrue(first: Boolean, vararg other: Boolean): Boolean {
    return first && other.all { it }
}

val result = isAllTrue(
    student.firstName == "John",
    student.lastName == "Smith",
    student.age == 20,
    student.cellPhone.orEmpty().startsWith("123456")
)
```

or

```
fun Iterable<Boolean>.isAllTrue(): Boolean {
    return all { it }
}

val result = listOf(
    student.firstName == "John",
    student.lastName == "Smith",
    student.age == 20,
    student.cellPhone.orEmpty().startsWith("123456")
).isAllTrue()
```

Comment: please revise your answer... you forgot to handle the nullable-type-issue...

Comment: Are you talking about the string "student.firstName ==" John "" where the `firstName` parameter is used as `String?`?

Comment: From the question we see that `student` can be `null` already... so I rather meant `student?.firstName`, etc... Note also that with your current approach you lose the short-circuiting and unnecessarily create a list for each such condition...

Comment: I'd go for the first one but instead of listOf i'd go for setOf because it's faster than a list.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what OP wants, but it seems like the issue here is comparing between two objects of type `Student` rather than chaining predicates.

Not sure what the use case is but here's a more object-oriented solution, where we park the predicates under `Student::isSimilarToJohn` (because I'm assuming this John Smith is pretty special):

```kotlin
data class Student(
    val firstName: String?,
    val lastName: String?,
    val age: Int?,
    val homeAddress: String?,
    val cellPhone: String?,
) {
    fun isSimilarToJohn(): Boolean {
        return firstName == "John" &&
            lastName == "Smith" &&
            age == 20 &&
            homeAddress == "45 Boot Terrace" &&
            cellPhone.orEmpty().startsWith("123456")
    }
}
```

Example:

```kotlin
val students = listOf(
    Student("John", "Smith", 20, "45 Boot Terrace", "1234568"),
    Student("John", "Smith", 20, "45 Boot Terrace", "1234567"),
    Student("Mary", "Smith", 20, "45 Boot Terrace", "1234567"),
    Student("John", "Doe",   20, "45 Boot Terrace", "1234567"),
)
students.map { it.isSimilarToJohn() }
// [true, true, false, false]
```